# Can't delete Dir/Files after using File.open block

Tags: ruby, file-io

When trying to delete a directory (+ contents) and after reading the files inside, `FileUtils.rm_rf(path)` will not delete all the folders, although it does delete all the files and *some* of the folders.

After some experimentation it seems to be related to a File.open block. (I actually do a regex match inside the block, but I'm just using a puts here to keep things clear)

```
File.open(file).each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

From what I've read, the above should automatically close the file but when using this, FileUtils fails to complete its task.

However, if I use the following code, FileUtils works as desired.

```
open_file = File.open(file)
open_file.each do |line|
  puts line
end
open_file.close
```

It's no big deal to use the code in the second example, but I do prefer the cleanliness of the first.

Is there any reason why that first example breaks FileUtils?

*P.S. I'm new to both Ruby and Stack Overflow....Hi. My system is Ubuntu 11.04 (64bit), running RVM with Ruby 1.9.2-p180*

Comment: When I pass the filenames I am actually passing the whole path; /media/drive/filea/a.html. The only thing I do within the directory "filea" is run a `Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*")` to get the list of filenames (a.html, etc.) - perhaps it's that. I'll do a test on this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
File.open(file) do |f|
  f.each{|line| puts line}
end
```

In your example the block is supplied to the each method and the version of open without a block is executed returning an IO object on which the each method is called.

Comment: When I try this I get an error on .each. After a little more checking it seems that when using `File.open(file).each do |line|` it is actually iterating over each line of the file. A further test, using `puts "-- #{line}"`, displays each line prefixed with two dashes.

Comment: The problem with your code is that `File.open(file).each do |line|` won't close the file afterwards. The reason for that is that `File.open` only closes the file if a block is given. And in your case the block is given to `each` and not to `open`.

Comment: Thanks obrok, I completely missed that I was still passing it to `each`.